# NodeGit: move branch pointer to different commit without checkout

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

In git we can use following command to achieve it:

```
git branch -f branch-name new-tip-commit
```

How do we achieve the same in nodegit?

http://www.nodegit.org/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and re-create the branch, forcing the creation even if it exists already.

See [Repository.prototype.createBranch (`lib/repository.js#L28-L39`)](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/232dbb19116c58d22cd7afd7435ee0bbe063f85b/lib/repository.js#L28-L39), which includes:

```
 @param {bool} force Overwrite branch if it exists
```

You can see an example in [`examples/create-branch.js#L4-L16`](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/44779afd0d460011e13a5cba9a47a48119aa472e/examples/create-branch.js#L4-L16):

```
var nodegit = require("../");
var path = require("path");

nodegit.Repository.open(path.resolve(__dirname, "../.git"))
  .then(function(repo) {
    // Create a new branch on head
    return repo.getHeadCommit()
    .then(function(commit) {
      return repo.createBranch(
        "new-branch",
        commit,
        0,
        repo.defaultSignature(),
        "Created new-branch on HEAD");
    });
  }).done(function() {
    console.log("All done!");
  });
```

If you replace the `0` by a `1` in that example, that would force the creation of that branch even if it already existed, effectively resetting its HEAD to the new commit.

Comment: Thanks it worked but it fails if branch is currently checked out. What about git reset --hard <commit>

Comment: @adnankamili https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/blob/44779afd0d460011e13a5cba9a47a48119aa472e/test/tests/reset.js#L181-L184